# Google Cloud Storage upload with signed URLs gives cors problems on actual request

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

I have a weird problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket where I want to upload files to from a webpage. In my backend (App Engine) I have created signed URLs that can be used for uploading the files. When I use that signed URL in Postman with a PUT request and a file, the file is successful uploaded to my bucket.

When I do the same from a webpage, than it becomes tricky. 
I have created the following code in my webpage:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PUT", resp.url);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", parameters.contentType);
req.onload = function(event) {
    this.loadFileList();
}.bind(this);
req.send(this.$.fileInput.files[0]);
```

This gave me CORS problems on the preflighted request (OPTIONS). After some reading I figured out to set the CORS configuration on Google Cloud Storage. So I have set the following configuration:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://my-website"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "POST"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

When I put this configuration onto Google Cloud Storage I see that the preflighted request starts to work, but then the actual request still fails with the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/[my-bucket].appspot.com/games/dev/game-[game]/game-pictures/[file].jpg?GoogleAccessId=[account]&Expires=[expires]&Signature=[signature].
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

(I replaced some parts of the url, so that I'm not exposing anything about my bucket)

The actual error is true. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing in the response of the actual request, but it's there in the response of the preflighted request.

So, should I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response of the actual request? And why don't I get that? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? We are seeing the exact same problem - the access-control-allow-origin header doesn’t appear to be returned from cloud storage on the actual second put request. The preflight succeeds.

Comment: Please see this thread that includes more detail answers https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/347

Answer (score 1):

The [Server Side Support docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support) have a table with details on when CORS headers are and are not included in the response. Such as:

> Cloud Storage supports the following methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST,
> PUT.
>
> Cloud Storage checks the methods sent from the browser in the
> Access-Control-Request-Methods header against the bucket's CORS
> configuration. **If there is no match, Cloud Storage Cloud Storage
> returns a 200 response code without CORS response headers.**

Also, when I used "copy as cURL" for the failed request from devtools it looks like there was a signing error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>PUT

multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGifzYccScMi2jEzj
1630635088
/bucketname/new/file.txt</StringToSign></Error>
```

So my guess is if your signing options are not correct, the `server: UploadServer` that generates the error response does not include the CORS headers.

Probably best to validate first using a signed URL from gsutil like:

```
URL=`gsutil -i $SERVICEACCOUNT signurl -u -d 1h -m PUT gs://$BUCKET/new/file.txt`
curl -v $URL -X 'PUT' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'origin: http://localhost:8080' --data ./file.txt --compressed

# Results should include access-control* headers for CORS
< HTTP/2 200 
< x-guploader-uploadid: ADPy...
< x-goog-generation: 16305....
< x-goog-metageneration: 1
< x-goog-hash: crc32c=Cx4mug==
< x-goog-hash: md5=aSdB8rjrH83Qj8h1GY0yUw==
< x-goog-stored-content-length: 16
< x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-expose-headers: Authorization, Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, User-Agent, X-GUploader-UploadID, X-Google-Trace, cache-control, x-goog-resumable, x-requested-with
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 02 Sep 2021 03:08:56 GMT
< server: UploadServer
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
< 
* Connection #0 to host storage.googleapis.com left intact
```

Answer (score -3):

Please read the following article which explains clearly how to solve cors while making a calls using java script. 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: I have read the article that you linked, but I'm already doing it like that. I can't find any difference with my implementation.

Comment: On the documentation given in the comment above, there's a link to this tutorial (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), that answers your first question. It's a yes. I believe that if you go through the tutorial you'll have an answer to the third question, and maybe get closer to an answer on the second one question.

Comment: I read the article but the answers to questions 2 and 3 are not obvious. Can you provide any further help?